# Calculating number of equivalence classes where two points are equivalent if they can be joined by a continuous path.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, equivalence-relations, path-connected

> Q. Let $G$ be an open set in $\Bbb R^n$. Two points $x,y \in G$ are said to be equivalent if they can be joined by a continuous path completely lying inside $G$. Number of equivalence classes is
>
> 1. Only one.
> 2. At most finite.
> 3. At most countable.
> 4. Can be finite, countable or uncountable.

This question was asked in the NET exam December 2016.

We can discard the first option by taking $n=1$ and $G=(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$.

We can reject the second option by taking $n=1$ and $G=\cup_{k \in \Bbb Z} (k,k+1).$

Now fun begins. Can we get an uncountable number of disjoint open path connected subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ for some $n$? If so, then we can take $G$ to be their union. For $n=1$, this method fails because that would give us the contradiction that the set of irrational numbers is countable.

Comment: I don't follow what you're trying to say in the case $n=1$ at all...

Comment: (3) follows from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640491/every-open-subset-o-of-bbb-rd-d-geq-1-can-be-written-as-a-countable-unio

Comment: @EricWofsey which statement about $n=1$? I have mentioned three cases. First rejected option 1. Second rejected option 2. and third gave me contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, I mean in the final sentence.

Comment: @EricWofsey It's ok. My argument in the final sentence was if we suppose $G=\cup_{i} (q_i,q_{i+1})$ where $q_i \in \Bbb R - \Bbb Q$, then that would mean $q_i$s are countable.  I am feeling like dumb now. :/

Comment: @Mathmore How do you get a contradiction here?It never says $\mathbb R- \mathbb Q$. right?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan Apparently those last three lines are nonsensical. Even I don't know what I was thinking back then. As you can see my comment above, it also doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Mathmore ok bro. I didn't understand while reading. That's why I asked you.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan No problems. Comments are meant to clarify about OP. I would have done same if I'd come across such post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is impossible to have uncountably many equivalence classes.  Note that each equivalence class is an open set, since balls are path-connected and so if $x\in G$ then any open ball around $x$ contained in $G$ is in the same equivalence class.  Now any nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ contains an element of $\mathbb{Q}^n$, so each equivalence class must contain some element of $\mathbb{Q}^n$.  Since $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is countable, there can be only countably many equivalence classes.

More generally, this argument applies with $\mathbb{R}^n$ replaced by any locally path-connected separable space.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the general case of 'locally path-connected separable space.'

Comment: This proof seems incorrect to me. Suppose $G=\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$. Then each arc-wise connected component of $G$ is of the form $\{ q \}$ where $q$ is a rational number. This set $\{ q \}$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$, and it is not even (relatively) open in $G$.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen $G$ is given to be an open set.  How can we take $G=\Bbb Q$ ?

Comment: Ah, I thought there would be something I had misunderstood. Thanks.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen No problems.

Answer (score 3):

As an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is the union of at most a countable number of open balls (centered on points with rational coordinates and having a rational radius), response 3. is the right one.

Comment: @VikrantDesai The point here is that any open set _can_ be represented as a union of balls with rational centers and radii. I'd consider it to be a nice exercise to show this if you've never seen a proof.

Comment: @Wojowu Okay. True that. I am also thinking same about writing down the proof for it. Will surely try.