# Open sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$ written as union of partially open cubes

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

We know that an open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ can be written as union of disjoint closed cubes ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/640491/281040) for example).
In Zygmund's book it is left to reader the fact that the same open set can be written as a **countable union of disjoint partly open cubes**. I don't know how to proceed in this case. I believe one should follow the idea in 1-dimensional case, taking intervals like
$$ [a_1,b_1) \cup [a_2,b_2) \cup \ldots$$
How does the proof linked [above](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/640491/281040) change? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean open sets in $\Bbb R^n$ are unions of "almost" disjoint cubes
(interiors are disjoint).

The idea in the linked post works here too.

For a start consider the set of cubes $[a_1,a_1+1)\times\cdots\times[a_n,a_n+1)$
with $a_i\in\Bbb Z$. Start off by taking all those contained in your open set $U$
and let their union be $V_0$.

Now consider cubes $[a_1/2,a_1/2+1/2)\times\cdots\times[a_n/2,a_n/2+1/2)$
again with $a_i\in\Bbb Z$ and take those contained in $U-V_0$. Let $V_1$
be the union of $V_0$ and these cubes.

After the $k$-th stage you have a subset $V_{k-1}$ of $U$ which is
a disjoint union of cubes and $U-V_{k-1}$ contains no cube
$[a_1/2^{k-1},a_1/2^{k-1}+1/2^{k-1})\times\cdots\times[a_n/2^{k-1},a_n/2^{k-1}+1/2^{k-1})$ with integer $a_i$.
Then $V_k$ will be the union of $V_{k-1}$ with the
$[a_1/2^k,a_1/2^k+1/2^k)\times\cdots\times[a_n/2^k,a_n/2^k+1/2^k)$ within
$U-V_k$.

Finally, $\bigcup_k V_k$ is a disjoint union of "half-open" cubes
and one shows that $U$ being open entails that $U=V_k$.

Comment: sorry, but it would be $ U = \bigcup_k V_k$ ?