# Sequence of cuboids $\left \{ (x_1, . . . , x_n) ∈ R^n : 2^{−k} j_i ≤ x_i < 2^{−k} (j_i + 1)\right \}$ with $U=\bigcup_{l∈N }Q_l$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have problems with this exercise. Can someone help me?
I have to show that for every open set $U ⊆ R^n$ there is a sequence $(Q_l)_{l∈N}$ of pairwise disjoint semi-open cuboids of the form

$\left \{  (x_1, . . . , x_n) ∈ R^n : 2^{−k} j_i ≤ x_i < 2^{−k} (j_i + 1)\right \}$

with $k ∈ N$ and $j_1, . . . , j_n ∈ \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$U=\bigcup_{l∈N }Q_l$

Comment: What have you tried ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: I don't know how to start

Comment: Does this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3137124/open-sets-in-mathbbrd-written-as-union-of-partially-open-cubes answer your question?